# Clone Audio object

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am aware of how to clone an object, but I'm wondering, how do I clone an audio object? Should I clone it differently than I would clone an object?

To "illustrate" what I mean:

```
var audio = new Audio("file.mp3");
var audio2 = $.extend({}, audio); // Clones `audio`
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Reason why I'm asking this is that I want to be able to play the same sound multiple times simultaneously.

Comment: `var audio = new Audio("file.mp3");var audio2 = new Audio("file.mp3")`

Comment: @Musa right, but is that slow?

Comment: Idon't know, do some benchmarks and see. Also there is `var audio2 = audio.cloneNode();`

Comment: @MiJyn, If you mean slow as in having to download the file again, no.  The browser will load it from cache.

Comment: @Brad, okay, thanks! That clarifies a lot

Comment: @Musa, after further testing, `$.extend` doesn't work (it gives an error), `new Audio` works, and even is faster than `$.extend`, though `play`ing it takes some time before it starts, and same with `audio.cloneNode()`. Are there any faster techniques?

Answer (score 11):

I had exactly the same predicament as originally raised.  The following worked perfectly well for me :

```
var audio2 = audio.cloneNode();
```

Comment: Seems like the browser makes a new request (for the same file) every time you invoke this.

Answer (score 7):

This question is ancient in javascript years.  I think your code is (was) downloading the audio again and that was the cause of your delay.  If you grab the audio file once and store it in a blob, you can then use that blob as the source for new audio events.

```
let fileBlob;
fetch("file.mp3")
    .then(function(response) {return response.blob()})
    .then(function(blob) {
        fileBlob=URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        new Audio(fileBlob); // forces a request for the blob
 });

 ...
 new Audio(fileBlob).play()  // fetches the audio file from the blob.
```

You can also do a lot of stuff with the [web audio api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), but it has a slightly steeper learning curve.

Comment: I do this, but it still shows a request in the Network log each time "New Audio()" is invoked, and while it shows a size of "0 B" transferred, it does report a differing load time every time instead of what you might expect as instant if it's truly "available".

Comment: @MattTreichel  You might have disabled the cache in your dev tools window.  If you disable the cache, the blob gets "fetched" every time, taking 0-3 ms depending on the phase of the moon.  If you re-enable your cache you should see those request disappear.

Answer (score -1):

#1

```js
let audio_2 = audio_1.slice()
```

or

#2

```js
let audio_2 = new Blob([audio_1])
```